Efficient algorithm for graph problem
Let $D=(V,E)$ be a directed graph, $S,T\subset V$ and $f:V\rightarrow \{1,\ldots, k\}$ a positive, bounded weight-function and $l\in \mathbb{N}$, find a path $v_1,\ldots, v_l\in V$ with $v_1\in S$ and $v_l \in T$ of minimal cost $\sum_{i=1}^lf(v_i)$.
The length of the path has to be precisely $l$. However, an algorithm that finds the best solution for a path of length $1, 2, \ldots, l$ would be even better.
I use Simplex (Gurobipy, if you are curious) to solve this problem. I think my formulation can be improved, but I am looking for other approaches or known problems to which this can be reduced. I can provide more information about the size of $V, E, k,\ldots$ if needed.
I don't know if this falls more into the jurisdiction of stack overflow. In that case, I'll repost the question there.
Edit: In case you are curious, the original problem is about the Italian Dominating Number.
Edit: The solution is in general not simple. Also, I'm looking for an optimal solution, not a heuristic.

Are you looking for a simple path?

No, the solution generally requires a path with repeating vertices and the graph is not acyclic.

Then a kind of $l$-step Dijkstra's algorithm (recording best cost values) should do the job. There is no need to employ solvers like Gurobi.

If $v_1$ and $v_l$ are fixed then constructing a minimum weight breadth-first tree of height $l{-}1$ and finally optimally attach vertex $v_l$.
Iterating over all candidate pairs of $v_1$ and $v_l$ would then yield the optimal solution.
Minimum weight breadth first trees seem to be the method of choice for controlling the number of edges of paths.
Addendum:
having learned that the paths need not be simple, we can reduce the fixed-cardinality shortest path to an ordinary shortest path problem as follows:
if we require a shortest path with exactly $l{-}1$ edges and the additional constraint that the start-vertex must be from a subset $S$ and the terminal vertex from a subset $T$ of $V$, we can achieve this as follows:

add a super-startvertex $\mathrm{A}$ and a super-terminalvertex vertex $\Omega$, that's analogous to RobPratts idea for solving the problem via cost-flows (but we are reducing the problem to an ordinary shortest path problem).

generate $n$  sets $V_1=S,V_2=V,\,\dots,\,V_{l{-}1}=V,V_l=T$ of vertices, each dedicated for path whose number of edges equal the index of the vertex set.

put the vertices of $S=V_1$ in the adjacency list of $\mathrm{A}$ and put $\Omega$ in the adjacency lists of vertices in $V_l=T$

replace the adjacency lists of vertices from $V_i$ with the corresponding  vertices (i.e. with the same label) from  $V_{i+1}$

calculate in the so generated graph the shortes path from $\mathrm{A}$ to $\Omega$


In case $S$ and $T$ are not disjoint, that would also be able generate a closed cycle as an answer; if that is not desired, it must be ruled out otherwise.

This approach can produce a non-simple path as I understand. It looks like OP want a simple path though.

@MaxAlekseyev in a tree every path is simple and I took the OP's request for simple paths into account; of course the suggested algorithm is only a heuristic that provides good solutions in reasonable time. Could you provide an example that generates non-simple paths?

OP confirmed that paths are not required to be simple. For simple paths, one would need to keep track of what vertices have been visited by subpaths when they are being contructed. I don't see such tracking in your proposed solution. Anyway, since OP does not require path simplicity, my comment is irrelevant.

@MaxAlekseyev what I have proposed can be demonstrated to be equivalent to an ordinary shortest path algorithm; in the absence of negative edgeweghts these algorithms never produce non-simple paths. But I see the need to add further information to my answer...

For shortest paths with nonnegative weights, non-simple paths are always worse than those obtained by removing cycles from them. However, when the "shortest" requirement is replaced by having a given length, non-simple paths may provide feasible solutions. E.g., in the graph formed by path 1-2-3 and cycle 2-4-5-2, a path of length 5 between vertices 1 and 3 is necessarily non-simple.

Also, finding a simple path of length $n-1$ in a graph on $n$ vertices means finding a Hamiltonian path, which emphasizes the complexity associated with finding simple paths of a given length.

@MaxAlekseyev I am aware of the problem and think it depends on the needs of people if an approximate solution is acceptable

A standard approach for handling a choice of sources and a choice of sinks is to introduce a supersource $s$ with a zero-cost arc to each $v\in S$ and a supersink $t$ with a zero-cost arc from each $v\in T$.  Now find a path from $s$ to $t$.  The successor of $s$ is your $v_1$, and the predecessor of $t$ is your $v_\ell$.

The normal A* algorithm can be modified to quit only at a path of the desired length. As @RobPratt suggested, two new vertices can avoid multiple sinks and sources.

If one is interested only in finding the minimal cost, then transfer-matrix method over the tropical semiring $R$ will do the job. Namely, consider the line digraph $G:=L(D)$ and its weighted adjacency matrix over $R$, raise it to the power $l-2$, and "sum up" (in $R$) the entries corresponding to the pairs of possible start and end edges in $G$ (corresponding to pairs of vertices from $S\times T$ in $D$) multiplied by their costs.
